# Flutter BlocBuilder displays previous state in TextFormField value

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-textformfield

I am trying to create a `TextFormField` with increment and decrement buttons and `TextFormField` is editable "by hand" as well. But there is a small problem if I use `BLoC` with this - `state` "falls" one behind, meaning that when I tap "+" first time nothing changes, but when I tap it the second time it changes its value to 21 (and so on..).
I tried the same implementation with just a regular `Text` and it works as expected and updating properly.

I'm just wondering if my logic of how I am setting `TextFormField` is flawed:

- Instantiating `TextEditingController` with default value amount (20);
- On "+" tap:

  - Adding `PlusEvent` to increment current value
  - Getting `amount` value from `state`

Widget class:

```
class MyCalculation extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCalculation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCalculation> createState() => _MyCalculationState();
}

class _MyCalculationState extends State<MyCalculation> {
  late TextEditingController _controller;
  late MyCalcBloc _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = context.read();
    _controller.text = _bloc.state.amount.toString();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MyCalcBloc, MyCalcState>(builder: (context, state) {
      return MyCustomTextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          onChanged: (value) {},
          onPlusTap: () {
            _bloc.add(PlusEvent());
            _bloc.text = '${state.amount}';
          },
          onMinusTap: () {});
    });
  }
}
```

BLoC class:

```
class MyCalcBloc extends Bloc<MyCalcEvent, MyCalcState> {
  MyCalcBloc() : super(const MyCalcState(amount: 20)) {
    on<IncrementFromEvent>(_onPlusEvent);
  }

  void _onPlusEvent(PlusEvent event, Emitter<MyCalcState> emit) {
    final newValue = state.amount + 1;
    emit(MyCalcState(amount: newValue));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate `TextEditingController` within `BlocProvider`, that way you'll get "current" `state` value displayed in `TextFormField`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<MyCalcBloc, MyCalcState>(builder: (context, state) {
      _controller = TextEditingController(text: state.amount.toString());
      return MyCustomTextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          onChanged: (value) {},
          onPlusTap: () {
            _bloc.add(PlusEvent());
            _bloc.text = '${state.amount}';
          },
          onMinusTap: () {});
    });
  }
```